# number: a savings / saving in time and money?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'd like to know whether "saving" or "Savings" should be used in the following:

> That move might mean **a** **saving** / **a** **savings** in time and money.

Traditional grammar would lead me to expect the singular "saving," but
I have seen the plural "savings" used after an indefinite article, as here.

Comment: The plural *savings* is normally only used in the specific context of a bank account, in which you have a *savings* ***account***. Otherwise, it's the singular form.

Comment: Is this wrong, then? Following the introduction of the computerised accounting process, savings were made of expenditure on quill pens, ink, and parchment.

Comment: ObGalaxyQuest: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgv7U3GYlDY

Comment: Apollyon - "savings" is after an indefinite article, not before, in your quoted text.

Comment: The plural is indeed used for things other than bank accounts, *pace* what some dictionaries say.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "traditional grammar".

Answer (score 2):

Saving can be a countable noun, or a plural one. Used countably, a single saving can be made: I made a saving on electricity costs when I changed to LED light bulbs. Also multiple (plural) savings can be made: The company made savings of time, money and staff use when it computerised a process.

*It will be a much simpler procedure and over a period of years will result in considerable savings of time and expense to the Government.*<sup>1</sup>

> Saving: plural savings
>   1. countable noun A saving is a reduction in the amount of time or money that is used or needed.
>
> Fill in the form below and you will be making a saving of £6.60 on a
>   one-year subscription. [+ of]
>
> ...a program of household savings on energy use.

Note there is also a plural use:

> 2. plural noun Your savings are the money that you have saved, especially in a bank or a building society.
>
> Her savings were in the Post Office Savings Bank.
>   ...a savings account.

[Saving (Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/saving)

Thus, addressing your example text:

**That move might mean a saving in time.

That move might mean a saving in money.

That move might mean savings in time and money.**

---

<sup>1</sup>from Decisions of the Comptroller General of the United States, Volume 26
Front Cover
U.S. Government Printing Office, 1946

Answer (score 1):

Both are used, though **savings** is the more often used.

[This graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20saving%20in%20time%20and%2Ca%20savings%20in%20time%20and&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20saving%20in%20time%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20savings%20in%20time%20and%3B%2Cc0) shows that the singular, "a saving", in that context is rapidly on the decline; and I'm basing my statement that **savings** is on the ascendant just from my sense of what I read these days.

Consider also [this graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=represents%20a%20saving%2Crepresents%20a%20savings&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crepresents%20a%20saving%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crepresents%20a%20savings%3B%2Cc0) for **represents a saving|savings**.  The phrase "a saving" has been on the decline.